# Are there special aliases that a mail provider would not want normal users to obtain

Tags: email, domain

Lets say, I would like to register a custom domain for email sending/receiving at Amazon AWS for a bunch of trusted users that can choose to send/receive mail with any valid mail address.

Are there still some special mail addresses that I (as the domain owner) should restrict for myself?

Are there special aliases that are defined by RFCs, that a mail domain owner should handle himself?

Comment: abuse@ and postmaster@ come to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [RFC 2142](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2142), which summarizes a number of common mail aliases that domains need to have. Some are required by other RFCs, such as postmaster@ and abuse@; others are merely examples, such as info@ or marketing@.

Which mailbox names you handle yourself, and which your customers handle, depends on the specifics of the relationship between you and your customers. You will need to consider each of them individually. For instance, if you manage the customer's website, then you would answer the webmaster@ address, but if they run their own website, then they probably should answer that address.

Comment: Per https://cabforum.org Baseline Rqts #3.2.2.4.4, 'one or more of' `admin administrator webmaster hostmaster postmaster` may be authorized to obtain certificate(s) for the domain (and subdomains of it). Example: https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/03/microsoft-takes-4-years-to-recover-privileged-tls-certificate-addresses/

Comment: RFC 2142 is in desperate need of an update...